# How to set a indefinite number of variables, specified by another variable

Tags: c++, variables, cnc, indefinite

Alright, I know that may sound confusing - I'm an new one on the idea of programming.
I have a CNC project that will take values from a text file, assign them, and transmit them via a serial connection to an Arduino which will receive and drive the motors, so on, so forth.

```
for( std::string line; getline( input, line ); ) 
{
int x, y;
input >> x >> y;
}
```

But, I want to be able to have the program process any length of a text file - any number of coordinates. In the interface I am designing a entry panel that would allow the user to specify the number of the commands. But, how do I introduce code that would take that number of commands and introduce that number of variables? I understand I could brute-force this by creating `1000` variables of each `X, Y, Z`, and other command types, and have up to `1000` possible line processing, but it would be much more efficient to have code that realizes this and adjusts for me.

Say, for example, I have that text entry box output a value designated `NumberOfCommands`. How would I tell the program to create a number of `X-axis, Y-axis, and Z-axis` (as well as other serial) commands where that number is equal to `NumberOfCommands`?

Comment: You probably want to find a [decent beginner's book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/179910) and read about `std::vector` about now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `std::vector` class to store any number of elements.

So in your case something like this :

```
struct Coordinate {
    int x,y,z;
};

std::vector<Coordinate> coords;

for( std::string line; getline( input, line ); ) 
{
   Coordinate coord;
   input >> coord.x >> coord.y >> coord.z;
   coords.push_back(coord);
}
```

Or with `emplace_back`:

```
struct Coordinate {
    Coordinate(int x, int y, int z):x(x),y(y),z(z){ }
    int x,y,z;
};

std::vector<Coordinate> coords;
int x,y,z;    
for( std::string line; getline( input, line ); ) 
{
   input >> x >> y >> z;
   coords.emplace_back(x,y,z);
}
```

`emplace_back` doesn't make a copy like `push_back` does, it creates and puts the element in the vector.

Comment: Now, in the form x(x),y(y),z(z); is the x/y/z notated in parenthesis the number? That is, could I notate in the code serial.write(x(4)) for the fourth set of coordinates?

Comment: The `x` inside the paranthesis is the parameter `x` passed to the constructor, which is the first parameter of `emplace_back`. The `x` outside the paranthesis is the member variable `x`. When you are sending it to `serial.write` you will do `serial.write(coords[0].x)` to send the 0th element's `x` member.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  arrays that are sized dynamically.

for example [from here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1601/):

```
int *myArray;           //Declare pointer to type of array
myArray = new int[x];   //use 'new' to create array of size x
myArray[3] = 10;        //Use as normal (static) array
...
delete [] myArrray;     //remember to free memory when finished.
```

The question is where does `x` come from? You could assume 1000 and keep a count as you fill the array. Then if you get more info than that size you could resize the array.

Or you could start with a entity to start with like an STL `vector<int>`

Comment: This is C++ not C. Please don't advise using arrays, especially combined with naked pointers: this is the best way to screw things up.